eBPF returning weird values for socket family
I'm trying to write a small eBPF program to capture per process network I/O statistics. I'm using kprobe and kretprobes attached to sock_recvmsg and sock_sendmsg to track any messages sent and received on a socket.
Because there's different types of sockets, I'm trying to filter these to only AF_INET and AF_INET6 to be sure they're "internet" sockets.
When trying to access sk->__sk_common.skc_family I get seemingly random numbers rather than an address family.
#define AF_INET    2
#define AF_INET6   10

SEC("kprobe/sock_recvmsg")
int kprobe_sock_recvmsg(struct sock *sk)
{

    u16 family;
    bpf_probe_read_kernel(&family, sizeof(family), &sk->__sk_common.skc_family);
    bpf_printk("kprobe/sock_recvmsg family 3: %d", family);

    if (family == AF_INET || family == AF_INET6) {
        u32 tid = bpf_get_current_pid_tgid() >> 32;
        bpf_printk("kprobe/sock_recvmsg tid: %d", tid);
        u32 value = 1; // is internet socket
        bpf_map_update_elem(&inetsocket, &tid, &value, BPF_ANY);
    }

    return 0;
}

 systemd-logind-1970    [000] ...21 71721.952455: bpf_trace_printk: kprobe/sock_recvmsg family 3: 63824
  systemd-logind-1970    [000] ...21 71721.952458: bpf_trace_printk: kprobe/sock_recvmsg family 3: 63824
  systemd-logind-1970    [000] ...21 71721.952462: bpf_trace_printk: kprobe/sock_recvmsg family 3: 63824
     dbus-broker-1978    [000] ...21 71721.952472: bpf_trace_printk: kprobe/sock_recvmsg family 3: 24800
     dbus-broker-1978    [000] ...21 71721.952488: bpf_trace_printk: kprobe/sock_recvmsg family 3: 24800
         systemd-1       [000] ...21 71721.952518: bpf_trace_printk: kprobe/sock_recvmsg family 3: 47312
         systemd-1       [000] ...21 71721.952521: bpf_trace_printk: kprobe/sock_recvmsg family 3: 47312
         systemd-1       [000] ...21 71721.952557: bpf_trace_printk: kprobe/sock_recvmsg family 3: 46112
     dbus-broker-1978    [000] ...21 71721.952567: bpf_trace_printk: kprobe/sock_recvmsg family 3: 24800
     dbus-broker-1978    [000] ...21 71721.952595: bpf_trace_printk: kprobe/sock_recvmsg family 3: 24800
         systemd-1       [000] ...21 71721.952602: bpf_trace_printk: kprobe/sock_recvmsg family 3: 46112
         systemd-1       [000] ...21 71721.952605: bpf_trace_printk: kprobe/sock_recvmsg family 3: 46112
     dbus-broker-1978    [000] ...21 71721.952930: bpf_trace_printk: kprobe/sock_recvmsg family 3: 24800
     dbus-broker-1978    [000] ...21 71721.952959: bpf_trace_printk: kprobe/sock_recvmsg family 3: 24800
  systemd-logind-1970    [000] ...21 71721.952977: bpf_trace_printk: kprobe/sock_recvmsg family 3: 63824
  systemd-logind-1970    [000] ...21 71721.952980: bpf_trace_printk: kprobe/sock_recvmsg family 3: 63824
  systemd-logind-1970    [000] ...21 71721.953002: bpf_trace_printk: kprobe/sock_recvmsg family 3: 63824
  systemd-logind-1970    [000] ...21 71721.953004: bpf_trace_printk: kprobe/sock_recvmsg family 3: 63824
  systemd-logind-1970    [000] ...21 71721.953009: bpf_trace_printk: kprobe/sock_recvmsg family 3: 63824
     dbus-broker-1978    [000] ...21 71721.953018: bpf_trace_printk: kprobe/sock_recvmsg family 3: 24800
     dbus-broker-1978    [000] ...21 71721.953033: bpf_trace_printk: kprobe/sock_recvmsg family 3: 24800
         systemd-1       [000] ...21 71721.953052: bpf_trace_printk: kprobe/sock_recvmsg family 3: 47312
         systemd-1       [000] ...21 71721.953055: bpf_trace_printk: kprobe/sock_recvmsg family 3: 47312
         systemd-1       [000] ...21 71721.953086: bpf_trace_printk: kprobe/sock_recvmsg family 3: 46112
     dbus-broker-1978    [000] ...21 71721.953096: bpf_trace_printk: kprobe/sock_recvmsg family 3: 24800
     dbus-broker-1978    [000] ...21 71721.953122: bpf_trace_printk: kprobe/sock_recvmsg family 3: 24800
         systemd-1       [000] ...21 71721.953129: bpf_trace_printk: kprobe/sock_recvmsg family 3: 46112
         systemd-1       [000] ...21 71721.953131: bpf_trace_printk: kprobe/sock_recvmsg family 3: 46112
     dbus-broker-1978    [000] ...21 71721.953361: bpf_trace_printk: kprobe/sock_recvmsg family 3: 24800
     dbus-broker-1978    [000] ...21 71721.953388: bpf_trace_printk: kprobe/sock_recvmsg family 3: 24800
  systemd-logind-1970    [000] ...21 71721.953406: bpf_trace_printk: kprobe/sock_recvmsg family 3: 63824
  systemd-logind-1970    [000] ...21 71721.953409: bpf_trace_printk: kprobe/sock_recvmsg family 3: 63824
     dbus-broker-1978    [000] ...21 71721.953667: bpf_trace_printk: kprobe/sock_recvmsg family 3: 24800
     dbus-broker-1978    [000] ...21 71721.953689: bpf_trace_printk: kprobe/sock_recvmsg family 3: 24800
 systemd-journal-1040    [000] ...21 71721.953715: bpf_trace_printk: kprobe/sock_recvmsg family 3: 44928
  systemd-logind-1970    [000] ...21 71721.954150: bpf_trace_printk: kprobe/sock_recvmsg family 3: 65280
  systemd-logind-1970    [000] ...21 71721.954182: bpf_trace_printk: kprobe/sock_recvmsg family 3: 65280
            sshd-34026   [000] ...21 71721.966731: bpf_trace_printk: kprobe/sock_recvmsg family 3: 0
            sshd-34026   [000] ...21 71722.882763: bpf_trace_printk: kprobe/sock_recvmsg family 3: 0
         chronyd-2344    [000] ...21 71723.011551: bpf_trace_printk: kprobe/sock_recvmsg family 3: 3520
         chronyd-2344    [000] ...21 71723.011883: bpf_trace_printk: kprobe/sock_recvmsg family 3: 3520
         chronyd-2344    [000] .N.21 71739.299375: bpf_trace_printk: kprobe/sock_recvmsg family 3: 3520
         chronyd-2344    [000] ...21 71739.299738: bpf_trace_printk: kprobe/sock_recvmsg family 3: 3520

None of the address families seem to be valid, for things I'd expect to be over an AF_INET, like sshd, I'm unsure why that returns a 0

The argument of your ebpf program is wrong, the first arg is not struct sock *sk but is struct socket *sock.
int sock_recvmsg(struct socket *sock, struct msghdr *msg, int flags)

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.13/source/net/socket.c#L902
